# Can anyone enlighten me as to why this swagger file is throwing errors?

Tags: swagger-2.0, power-automate, connector

While creating a custom connector for Power Automate, I'm getting the following error with the swagger (no validation errors are occurring & I have checked it via multiple editors),

```
The request failed with client error: '{"Code":"","Message":"GET https://power-apim-europe-001.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/873e5639-9775-4e58-ac59-935e3f7dbc6c/resourceGroups/apim-power-europe-001/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/power-apim-europe-001/apis/smartsheet-20api-5f83fde20557d336df-5f8f194df2cac2ec5c?import=true&protocols=https&path=apim%2fsmartsheet-20api-5f83fde20557d336df-5f8f194df2cac2ec5c&api-version=2019-01-01&asyncId=623a42ef47fc0015e44853aa&asyncCode=201 failed with BadRequest, content={\"error\":{\"code\":\"ValidationError\",\"message\":\"One or more fields contain incorrect values:\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"ValidationError\",\"target\":\"value[121].urlTemplate\",\"message\":\"URL template is invalid\"}]}}","Target":null,"Details":[],"Innererror":null}'. The correlation Id is '7eabc939-4c3f-484e-bdbd-b4568844c321'.
```

[Pastebin - Swagger File](https://pastebin.com/UF00YYC8)
(pasted to pastebin due to SO character limit for question body)

I seem to be banging my head against a brick wall now, as the error message isn't helpful at all. Can anyone spot whats wrong here?

Comment: I don't know what's up with that giant URL but that swagger file works fine with the latest version of the [Swagger codegen CLI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen).

Comment: @stdunbar that's the issue, I've validated the file via multiple editors including Swagger Hub, yet "one or more fields contains incorrect values"... I've even resorted to manually attempting to validate the file, but so far have come up with nothing.